# Adding New Localization as Array

Tags: swift, localization, localizable.strings

I would like to add a list of strings to Localization. How can I add that one ass array? I mean:

> "home.list" = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

Is it possible in swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
"home.list" = "A,B,C,D"
```

Then use like

```
let arr = NSLocalizedString("home.list", comment: "").components(separatedBy: ",")
```

Comment: but I need this data to table view

Comment: arr is `[String]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the localized strings separate:

```swift
"stringA" = "A";
"stringB" = "B";
"stringC" = "C";
"stringD" = "D";
```

And then build an array:

```swift
let array = [
    NSLocalizedString("stringA", comment: ""),
    NSLocalizedString("stringB", comment: ""),
    NSLocalizedString("stringC", comment: ""),
    NSLocalizedString("stringD", comment: "")
]
```

You can't directly create an array in your Localizable files, or atleast I'm not aware of that possibility.